# Angular CLI ng serve va muy lento

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli

Tengo una **API** en **Symfony-PHP**, la cual pruebo con **postman** y funciona rápido. Pero cuando hago `ng serve --aot --optimization` empieza a construirse la aplicación y el mensaje de `compiled successfully.` tarda más de un minuto en salir.
Cuando necesito hacer un cambio en un componente `html` como puede ser una letra, me re-compila todo el proyecto y tarda demasiado para un cambio tan pequeño.

El parámetro `--watch` está a `true` por defecto, lo cual me viene bien. No se si alguien sabe porque esta compilación es tan lenta.

**Versiones:**

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.2
Node: 8.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.8.2
@angular-devkit/core         0.8.2
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.8.2
@schematics/angular          0.8.2
@schematics/update           0.8.2
rxjs                         6.2.2
typescript                   2.9.2


oscar@ubuntu:~$: ng s --aot --optimization


****************************************************************************************
This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications locally.
It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

DON'T USE IT FOR PRODUCTION!
****************************************************************************************
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
 10% building modules 7/8 modules 1 active ...s\orquestados-front-user\src\styles.cssBrowserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `n 70% building modules 646/646 modules 0 activei ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /pages/offer/management/219702                                             92% chunk asset optimization TerserPlugini ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /pages/offer/management/219702
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /pages/offer/management/219702
Date: 2019-09-30T08:30:18.736Z
Hash: 9afdb6037df5643d0cb2
Time: 512136ms
chunk {0} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.3 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 62 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 45.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 1020 kB [initial] [rendered]
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: ¿Estás usando ubuntu en una máquina virtual o como máquina física? ¿Cuánta RAM tienes? Todo apunta a que tiene insuficiente RAM para hacer el trabajo con soltura y echa mano de la partición de paginación.

Comment: máquina física. Tengo 8 gb de ram y parece que tienes razón, PHPSTorm y Node son los que más recursos de RAM me están consumiendo. Alguna recomendación? 16GB de ram solucionarian algo?

Comment: No, no solucionaría el problema. Yo he estado trabajando en un portátil con 4 GB de RAM y todo iba bien (con Ubuntu real, no virtualizado). ¿Has probado a hacer un `iotop` durante la compilación para ver en qué se va el ancho de banda de disco? Quizá debas instalarlo con un `sudo apt install iotop`. ¿Cuánta RAM te ocupa cada proceso (PHPSTorm y Node)? ¿Qué versión de Ubuntu estás usando? Acabo de hacer una prueba tras actualizar node y angular y me da como tiempo de compilación `14642ms` (algo más de 14 segundos) en un proyecto en el que estuve trabajando (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS).

Comment: Sé que no se te podría haber ocurrido pero ¿Ya probaste sin mandarle parámetros al ng serve?

Comment: Esa es la respuesta @RuslanLópez, haciendo `ng s` tarda mucho menos tiempo. Gracias por recordarlo

Answer (score 1):

Leave out --optimization. Then the build on change will take much less time. Try also without --aot. First build always takes some time. But then incremental build takes just a few seconds.

Eliminar el parámetro `--optimization` y el de `--aot`. El build cuando detecte un cambio tarda mucho menos tiempo.
La priemra vez que hace build se demora un poco pero el resto sonmucho más rápidas.
Ahora mi tiempo de compilacion es de pocos segundops en vez de 8 minutos.

[image: output de la terminal con las muestras de tiempo]

Comment: Aún así esos tiempos siguen siendo demasiado elevados. Por poner un ejemplo de referencia, el [**tour of heroes**](https://angular.io/tutorial) (download example), me tarda (sin opciones adicionales) 8 segundos la primera vez y posteriormente 100-180 ms. Con las opciones `--aot --optimization` me tarda la primera vez 9 segundos y posteriormente 4 segundos tras modificar un archivo `html` o `ts`. ¿Qué procesador tienes? ¿Podrías probar con el **tour of heroes** para tener un punto de referencia?

Comment: Es un portatil Hp de la empresa. Procesador intel i3-5005U 2.00GHz.
Probaré con el ejemplo y comentaré resultados. Gracias tocayo

Comment: Un procesador portátil de gama U, es muy probable que tenga un IPC muy reducido (la capacidad de proceso de un único núcleo será muy reducido) y, por desgracia, node se ejecuta en un único proceso/hilo :( Es probable que tengas que abandonar la idea de hacer compilación continua con esas opciones en favor de la más rápida para mejorar tu productividad. Aún así, he de advertirte que los modelos U de Intel no son aptos para desarrollo ni diseño, más bien están pensados para un uso ofimático y navegación web.

Comment: Éste es el procesador (un i5-2450M) con el que he trabajado hasta hace un año y medio (me cambié a un i7-7700HQ): https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i3-5005U-vs-Intel-Core-i5-2450M/m24957vs2815 Aún siendo 3 generaciones (3 años) más viejo que tu procesador, tiene un 25% más de IPC pero solo algo más del 10% de rendimiento total (teniendo ambos 2 núcleos / 4 hilos). En algunos casos como el desarrollo en node (y personalmente también lo he notado desarrollando para Android) esa diferencia de potencia de un único núcleo mejora drásticamente los tiempos de compilación.

Comment: Gracias por la información. En este caso la empresa que me tiene contratado debería darme un equipo en condiciones. De todas formas nos hemops ido del tema. He solucionado el tiempo de compilación sin cambiar de hardware. El tema es, porqué era tan lento con `--aot` y `--optimization` ?

Comment: Pero ¿usabas esas opciones para probar en preproducción el resultado de producción mientras retocando el desarrollo o usaste esas opciones arbitrariamente? Si las empezaste a usar arbitrariamente entones la solución es, obviamente, no usar opciones que no necesites.